# How do you make sure goroutines finish in a for-loop using WaitGroup?

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, goroutine

I'm running a function in a goroutine each time a for-loop iterates, and I'm using `sync.WaitGroup` to make sure the goroutines all finish. However, I'm getting weird behavior testing the concurrency with counters. In the example below, I attempt to keep track of the thread count using 4 different techniques (`w`, `x`, `y`, `z`), and get 4 different results. The only result I understand is `x`, since it is incremented in the for-loop itself. What am I missing here?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

var w = 0

func main() {
  x := 0
  y := 0
  z := 0
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    x++
    go func() {
      z++
      test(&y)
      wg.Done()
    }()
  }
  wg.Wait()
  fmt.Println(w, x, y, z) // 8947 10000 8831 8816
}

func test(y *int) {
  w++
  *y++
}
```

Comment: The wait group is working as you expect.  The problem is that there's a data race on w, y, and z.

Comment: @CeriseLimón do I need to use a mutex to increment? what is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Use a mutex or [sync/atomic](https://godoc.org/sync/atomic).  It's difficult to comment on an efficient solution without seeing the actual problem you are solving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sync.Waitgroup` is working as expected. `w`, `y` and `z` will not reach 10000 because multiple goroutines are incrementing them concurrently, and Go's increment is not concurrent-safe: it is implemented as a normal fetch-increment-reassign operation.

You have two options.

#### option 1: mutex

```
type incrementer struct {
    sync.Mutex
    i int
}

func (i *incrementer) Add(n int) {
    i.Lock()
    defer i.Unlock()
    i.i += n
}
```

and use this type for `w`, `y` and `z`.

Full example: https://play.golang.org/p/6wWUK2xnOCW

#### option 2: sync.atomic

```
var w int32 = 0

go func(){
    // in the loop
    atomic.AddInt32(&w, 1)

}()
```

Full example: https://play.golang.org/p/oUCGgKYC1-Y